# Compile Rmarkdown outside of Rstudio

Tags: cmd, rstudio, r-markdown, rscript

I can use the `knit` button to compile an Rmarkdown file to html in Rstudio.

How can I do the same in an R console?

Answer (score 2):

In an R console, you can use the following command:

```
rmarkdown::render("input.Rmd")
```

Answer (score 2):

The command posted by **scoa**

```
rmarkdown::render("input.Rmd")
```

is ok, but outside RStudio you can receive error because pandoc version can be too old.

If so see  https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md

If you are on Linux you need just to link pandoc version from RStudio or RStudio Server.

Comment: "The command is ok": which one? The one posted by scoa? Please consider that this is not a forum, it's a Q&A site, and while for the moment there's only one answer apart from yours, in the future there could be more, and due to voting they could appear in any order. So if you refer to another answer, please explain clearly which one!

Comment: Command and user reference added, thanks to Fabio Turati comment!